# Typescript 2 enum referencing between interfaces and classes

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, enums, interface

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and Typescript 2.0 installed.  I'm working with Angular 2.

If I have a typescript file, like so:

MyEnums.ts:

```typescript
export enum myEnum { RED, BLUE, GREEN }
```

And I have an interface in a file like so:

types.ts:

```typescript
namespace MyTypes {
    export interface ISomeInterface {

        aMethod: (aColor: MyEnum) => void;

    }
    export interface IMyService {
        myMethod: () => void;
    }

}
```

An implementing class of the first interface:

SomeCode.ts:

```typescript
export class SomeClass implements ISomeInterface {

        public aMethod(aColor: MyEnum){

        }
        ...and so on
```

And an Angular service:

SomeCode.ts:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SomeClass } from "path to SomeClass file";
import { MyEnum } from "path to MyEnum file";

@Injectable()
export class MyService implements IMyService {

        public myMethod(){
            let localSomeClass: ISomeInterface = new SomeClass();
            localSomeClass.aMethod(MyEnum.RED);
        }
        ...and so on
```

Everything builds like a champ if I just put the enum in the types files, but of course things fail at runtime because there is no actual enum implementation existing.  When I make the files like above then VS can't find the enum definition for the type.ts file's ISomeInterface...

Does anyone know the correct way to reference an enum in a definition file and an implementing class file?

If I import the enum into the types.ts file with:

```typescript
import { MyEnum } from "path to MyEnum file";

namespace MyTypes {
    export interface ISomeInterface {
        ... 
}
```

then VS no longer finds and resolves the types.ts and SomeCode.ts no longer recognizes ISomeInterface.

Comment: ofcourse it can't. You have to import MyEnum into the types.ts file as you would any in any other file.

Comment: Question updated explaining why importing MyEnum like that causes a problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think your problem is mainly because you are combining namespaces (internal modules) and file based (es6) module types.